# Zip folder in python with optimization of memory usage

Tags: python, zip

Is there a way to decrease memory usage while compressing (creating a zip file ) a folder with several files?
The reason is that in large files it can consume a lot of memory. if there is a way to make performance better too I would love to know too

```
import os
import zipfile
import errnodef 

zip_folder(
    zip_source_directory_target,
    source_folder_to_zip_path,
    zip_file_name,
    logger: Logger,
    compresslevel=6,
):
    """
    do compression on a folder
    """
    if os.path.exists(source_folder_to_zip_path) and os.path.exists(
        zip_source_directory_target
    ):
        full_zip_directory = os.path.join(zip_source_directory_target, zip_file_name)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(
            full_zip_directory,
            "w",
            compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,
            compresslevel=compresslevel,
        ) as zipf:
            with os.scandir(source_folder_to_zip_path) as entries:
              for entry in entries:
                if entry.is_file():
                    arcname = os.path.relpath(entry.path, source_folder_to_zip_path)
                    zipf.write(entry.path, arcname=arcname)
    else:
        logger.warn(f"Zip source path: {zip_source_directory_target}")
        raise FileNotFoundError(
            errno.ENOENT,
            os.strerror(errno.ENOENT),
            f"Data folder path or zip source path may not exist please check",
        )
```

Edit:
tnx to Mark Adler
the solution is working (the one above)
the issue the second time was due to a false memory check with docker stats - an issue with the docker version

Comment: What makes you think it's consuming a lot of memory? I see nothing there that would.

Comment: when I check the memory with docker stats I see that it is up to 2GB for 3GB dir and when it done it return to 60MB

Comment: Are you using Python 2? There was a memory-leak bug in `os.walk`.

Comment: I am using Python 3

Comment: `os.scandir` would need to be used recursively in order to do the same thing as `os.walk`.

Comment: Quantify "a lot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) instead of `os.walk`. Your use of `os.walk` loads the entire directory tree into memory, and then iterates over it. `os.scandir` will return an iterator that steps through the tree without loading it all into memory.

Comment: It is still consuming a lot of memory in large files

Comment: You would need to update your question with your code.

Comment: done, can you check, please

Comment: tnx it working - issue with docker stats related to docker version with false memory usage